# Can I add new Googe Play Games achievements after publishing?

Tags: android

I have a game on Android that has a list of Google Play Games achievements. I'm planning to create new levels in the game so I would like to add new achievements for them. Is it possible? I ask it because I've read that it's impossible to remove already published achievements but have not found any information about adding new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've created test game and just tried. Answer: yes, it's possible.